# On abelian spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, polyhedra, cw-complexes

By Allen Hatcher's book, a space is called abelian if it has trivial action
of $\pi_1$ on all homotopy groups $\pi_n$, since when $n=1$ this is the condition that $\pi_1$
be abelian.

My quesion is that:

1. Is $S^1 \vee S^2$ an abelian polyhedron?
2. Is there an abelian polyhedron $P$ with abelian $\pi_1 (P)$ and infinitely generated  $H_i (\tilde{P},\mathbb{Z})$ for some $i\geq 2$?

Comment: 1. No, you can see this since pi_1 acts on pi_2 by translation of a generator. (What is the universal cover?)

Comment: 2. Sure. Take an infinite wedge of spheres

Comment: @AndresMejia Thanks a lot for the comment. The universal cover is $\mathbb{R}\vee S^2$. For the case (2), is there a finite ployhedron with those properties?

Comment: That is not the universal cover :) actually pi_2 is not finitely generated.

Comment: For your second question: I don’t think so. Try for example simplicial homology.

Comment: @AndresMejia Sorry, you are right. The universal covering is $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{Z}$ copies of $S^2$ wedged to integer numbers.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thank you so much for your guide. I'll try it.